# How to type a Tuple with type inference in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write the type signature of a function that replaces the values of an object with a list of changes to the object.

I'm having trouble finding the most accurate type for the function.

The function in question is:

```
export const patchObjFn = (
    defaultVal: any
) => <T extends object, K extends keyof T> (
    changeObj: Replacement<T>[] | Replacement<T>,
    moddingObj: T
) => {
    const moddedObj = cloned(moddingObj);
    const isSingleElement = changeObj.length !== 0
        && (changeObj.length === 1 || changeObj.length === 2)
        && !Array.isArray(changeObj[0]);
    const changes = isSingleElement
        ? [changeObj] as ([K] | [K, T[K]])[]
        : changeObj  as ([K] | [K, T[K]])[];
    for (const change of changes) {
        const [propName, val] = change.length === 1
            ? [change[0], defaultVal]
            : change;
        moddedObj[propName] = val;
    }
    return moddedObj;
};
```

And the type I've reached is:

```
export type Replacement<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = [K] | [K, T[K]];
```

But this doesn't really work, since if K is `'hello' | 'world'` and T is `{ hello: string; world: number; }`, we can pass in `['hello', 42]`.

I would like to prevent this, but am unsure how to do so.

Comment: [First shot](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9nA1gVzAHgCoBooGkB8UAvHlBAB7AQB2AJgM5SIQhwBmUGUA-JwNq4AulABcUahABuEAE4BuAFChIeAGoZUAGwj1MZSjQZQ4AIwBWEAMbAcuAMr6qdRgEEZMgIYg0zVhwz4hCQA3gpQUHwAklAAltRMLOx4doJiAnZRgjjwSKiYthmRgviCCgC+igqWcNT0wFAAtnC0YnoUTkamFtYFjoau7l4+if6BABRhUMBi2JOIkhpg2vRiuOpaOvnJhAA+EaUAlMSEXCTUyJqaAISV1bX15MSNzWPBUB5iAEQAFiyfOCYxABGHCWMTAGTIaBlHB8PifEz-KBArIRT4eJEo2HopGfJBeT6CQQHRRAA) but I'm going offline so someone else might have a more targeted answer

Comment: That's pretty interesting. How does the `KS[I]` know to narrow down the type to a specific value of `keyof T`?

Comment: I went a different route with the posted answer, but to answer your question, I was using a [mapped array/tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) and [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to infer an array of keys `KS` from the passed-in array of key-value tuples.  `KS[I]` just means the type of the `I`th element of the `KS` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to address just the typings and not the implementation. It's possible that this typing will cause some errors to appear inside your implementation; if so, it is likely that either you can change your implementation to appease the compiler or you can [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that your implementation matches the signature.  In either case, the question seems to be about how to prevent callers from passing mismatched key/value pairs, and not what's going on inside the function implementation.

I'm also going to ignore the `defaultVal` parameter and the curried function that takes it, because it complicates things trying to figure out just what type of object can possibly take a single default value for all its properties.   If `T` is `{ hello: string; world: number; }` and I pass in `[["hello"],["world"]]`, is `defaultVal` somehow both a `string` and a `number`?    As I said, I'm ignoring that.

---

So we'll come up with the signature of a function `patch` which takes an object of generic type `T` and a list of replacement key-value tuples appropriate to `T`, and returns a result also of type `T`:

```
declare function patch<T extends object>(
  t: T,
  kvTuples: Array<{ [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]?] }[keyof T]> | []
): T;
```

The interesting part is the type of the `kvTuples` parameter.  Let's take care of that `| []` at the end, there, first.  All this does is give the compiler [a hint](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) to interpret `kvTuples` as a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) and not as a plain array.  If you leave that off it won't change which inputs are accepted or not accepted, but the error messages will become completely incomprehensible as the entire input array will be flagged as wrong:

```
patch({ a: "hey", b: 1, c: true }, [
  ["a", "okay"], // error! 
  ["b", false], // error! 
  ["c", true] // error! 
]);
// string is not assignable to "a" | "b" | "c"
```

In the above, the `["b", false]` is the wrong entry, as the type of the `b` property should be `number`.  What you get though is a lot of errors that don't really point you to what you should be fixing.

Anyway, `kvTuples` is an `Array<Something>` where `Something` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) we do a [lookup](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) into.  Let's examine that type.  `{[K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]?]}` takes each property of `T` and turns it into a pair of key-value types (with the second element being [optional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#optional-elements-in-tuple-types)).

So if `T` is `{a: string, b: number, c: boolean}`, then the mapped type is `{a: ["a", string?], b: ["b", number?], c: ["c", boolean?]}`.  Then we use a lookup type to get the union of property value types.  So if we call the mapped type `M`, we are doing `M[keyof T]` or `M["a" | "b" | "c"]` or `M["a"] | M["b"] | M["c"]` or `["a", string?] | ["b", number?] | ["c", boolean?]`.  And *that's* the type we want for each element of the `kvTuples`.

Let's try it:

```
patch({ a: "hey", b: 1, c: true }, [
  ["a", "okay"],
  ["b", false], // error! 
  ["c", true]
]);
```

The error shows up in a reasonable place at least.  Less reasonable is the error message you get.  The following is at least vaguely okay:

```
// Type '(string | boolean)[]' is not assignable to type
// '["a", (string | undefined)?] | ["b", (number | undefined)?] |
// ["c", (boolean | undefined)?]'.
```

Since it didn't type check, the compiler is apparently saying that `["c", 7]` is of type `(string | number)[]`, which doesn't match the union of tuples.  That's true enough, but it yields an unfortunate last-line of the error message:

```
// Property "0" is missing  in type '(string | boolean)[]' 
// but required in type '["c", (boolean | undefined)?]'
```

That's not helpful, especially since it's talking about `"c"` for what seems like no reason to the user.  Still, at least the error shows up in the right place.  It is undoubtedly possible to make the error even more sensible, at the expense of more complexity in the signature of `patch`, which I fear is already complicated enough.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-Dovl0hlCpaAVD2gA)